# Line Chart leaving gaps in data

Tags: apache-flex, charts, rendering

I have a Flex line chart where I allow the user to change the y axis ranges.  When a data point falls outside the ranges, the chart drops the line segments on either side of the out of range point leaving a gap in the data line.

I'm currently using the data function to clamp the values out of range to the y axis min/max, but this displays misleading data.

Is there a way to make it draw the lines to the y axis max/min point, making it look like the line goes off the plot?

Comment: Why not also use a dataTipFunction to show the accurate number for the clamped values?

Comment: I do that, but unless the user suspects that's what is happening they might not mouse over the data.  I also add indicators to the chart to indicate that there is data above/below the range.  Also added hot keys to reset the y ranges to the min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter filterDataValues in LineSeries - set it to "none" and it should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck at Flex 3 for the time being.